# extern global seems to cause linker errors

Tags: c++, g++, extern

I'm having a strange situation where using a global object appears to cause unrelated linker errors.

My setup is as follows:

```
// globals.h
#ifndef GLOBALS_H
#define GLOBALS_H

class Singleton
{
...
};

extern Singleton* g_object;
#endif
```

```
// globals.cpp

#include "globals.h"

Singleton* g_object = new Singleton();
```

```
// somefile.cpp

#include "globals.h"

void function()
{
    g_object->do_some_stuff();
}
```

It looks like that when I try to use g_object somewhere, I get a lot of "undefined references" from the linker, but they all refer to some other, unrelated parts of the project and have nothing to do with my class or object or the functions that use it.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious and it screws up the objects somehow, but I can't quite figure out what, as far as I can tell declaring a global in an `.h` file and then providing the definition in a `.cpp` is the approved way of creating globals, what am I doing wrong?

P.S.

I use the following flags:
`-c -v -Wall -Wno-strict-aliasing -Weffc++ -Woverloaded-virtual -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -fstack-protector -fshort-wchar -fvisibility=hidden -fms-extensions -xc++ -fno-strict-aliasing -std=c++11 -fpermissive -Wno-narrowing -pthread -g -fPI`

Comment: Please change `exten` to `extern` in your first code block :)

Comment: Can you show us your flags when compiling?

Comment: @L.F. I've added the compiler flags

Comment: It would also be helpful if you provided the command you are using for linking... since that is where the errors are mentioned.  (And why is the header being brought in with `<globals.h>` with angled-brackets?  Very odd.)

Comment: @Eljay Whoops, the include brackets were a typo

Comment: without a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's hard to say, as your example cannot manifest the problem per se.

Comment: Unrelated: `Singleton* g_object = new Singleton();` suggests that a program could ask for multiple instances of `Singleton`. This doesn't jive with the common usage of the term singleton in programming. [Here's a link to an excellent way to make a singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/4581301)

Comment: @user4581301 yes, OP way is definitely a bad choice for a singleton but this should compile in any case.

Comment: The flags you have shown us are not relevant. They are for compilation only. Undefined reference errors are linkage errors. We have no information about your linkage. [mcve] needed.